# Problem executing TCL script from Bourne Shell (redirection trouble)

Tags: shell, redirect, tcl, arguments

I am working with VMD (a molecular dynamics visualization package) and I want to open VMD from a Perl script, run a Tcl script, print the output to a log file, then close VMD and return to the Perl script. The ordinary syntax to do this is:

```
system("vmd -dispdev text -eofexit < program.tcl > LOG");
```

which breaks down as follows, as best as I understand:

- `system("");`: executes Bourne Shell commands contained in quotes
- `vmd`: calls VMD
- `-dispdev text`: opens VMD in text mode
- `-eofexit`: terminates VMD when EOF on STDIN is reached
- `< prog.tcl`: sets `prog.tcl` as STDIN; vmd will terminate when `prog.tcl` completes
- `> LOG`: writes STOUT to file `<LOG>`

Now this would work perfectly, except that my Tcl script takes arguments. What I'd *like* to do is something like:

```
system("vmd -dispdev text -eofexit < program.tcl string1 string2 > LOG");
```

however, in this case the shell tries to read string1 and string2 as files. With my limited understanding of redirection, I'm not sure *exactly* what is going in the first line, what exactly goes wrong in the second, or what a good solution would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, don't think you can pass arguments to your Tcl script directly when its being executed within another program like vmd.  I would suggest passing the parameters via a file as a workaround. Eg.
In the Perl script, before calling vmd, write the parameters to a file in Tcl syntax:

```
open PARAMS, '>myparams.tcl';
print PARAMS "set arg1 $string1; set arg2 $string2";
close PARAMS;
```

Then at the start of program.tcl, instead of using command line arguments ($argv), have it read the parameter file to pick up the argument values:

```
source myparams.tcl
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know `source`. I have the VMD command running inside a loop, and I thought I was going to have to rewrite the entire Tcl script each time; this is much better. Too bad there's no way to pass the arguments directly though.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is sending the *contents* of the program.tcl file to vmd, not the output of executing the program.  If I understand you, you want to connect the Tcl program to vmd with a pipe:

```
system("program.tcl arg1 arg2 | vmd -... > output.file");
```

**Edit:**

So, if vmd reads Tcl code on stdin, you can still pass parameters without using a temp file:

```
system("( echo 'set arg1 str1; set arg2 str2'; cat program.tcl; ) | vmd ... > output_file");
```

or

```
open my $fh, '<', 'program.tcl';
my @tcl = <$fh>;
close $fh;
unshift @tcl, "set arg1 str1\n", "set arg2 str2\n";
open $fh, '|-', 'vmd ... > output.file' or die 'msg...';
print $fh join('', @tcl);
close $fh or die 'msg...';
```

Comment: In that case, the shell would attempt to execute `program.tcl` as a shell command. If I piped `./program.tcl arg1 arg2` to VMD it would only send the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arguments directly to VMD by doing something like

```
system(vmd -dispdev text -e program.tcl -args string1 string2 > LOG);
```

Make sure to add a `quit` statement at the end of `program.tcl`.